# Which is faster: a bank with five lines of ten or one line of fifty?

Tags: machine-learning, probability

I'm working on a probability question with mean and variance.

> Let's say that I have two banks. They are identical in every way,
>   except that bank A has five lines with ten people each and bank B has one
>   line with fifty people. There are five tells in each bank.
>
> In bank A, each of those tellers is dedicated to serving one line and
>   in bank B, the teller serves the next available customer. Which has a
>   faster average wait time and longer variance wait time?

I understand the first part of the question. The average wait time is the same because it is, in your line, the time to help each customer * the number of customers / the number of bank tellers.

For bank A, that's time * 10 / 1 and for bank B, it's time * 50 / 5.

I don't understand the second part of the question though. Intuitively, I think that bank B should have a longer standard deviation for wait time since there are more people and you have a greater chance at getting extreme outliers, or customers who take much longer than anyone else.

Comment: i think what the question implies re bank A is "five lines with ten people *each*". So the population sizes are equal. Otherwise the question does not make much sense.

Comment: here's an answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117151/does-a-single-line-result-in-shorter-average-queue-time

Comment: @Zhubarb, thank you. I updated for clarity.

Comment: @Edgar, the poster said it's easy to demonstrate the difference in variability between the two lines but I still don't see it.

Comment: There's also this - https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/one-queue-or-many-queues/

Comment: nice link! see also the exercise 7 here: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~frank/STOCHNET/ps1.pdf (linked on your reference). is this sufficient for your understanding? it surely isn't trivial, but it's mathematically rigorous.